# How to restore files, keeping original "Date Added"

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, restore

I had an automation problem with my Downloads folder (no doubt my fault), losing the correct filename for > 2,000 files. No prob: I'm obsessive about backups (internal Time Machine plus 2 external clones).

I restored the Downloads folder from TM, but that made all the dates in the Date Added the current date rather than the date I downloaded them. (Really, Apple? That's a "restore"?) Copying from a clone does the same thing. Anyone know how to restore that folder keeping the original Date Added dates?

Comment: out of curiosity if you open that folder in the Finder in list mode, right-click on the col. headings (name, size, etc.) and add "Date Created" from the pop up menu does it show what you want?

Comment: It appears that Date Created and Date Modified are the same for all the files.